# for loop in bash gives error

Tags: bash

One of my system have bash version 2.05.8, which is quite older. Now on this machine ii tried to use for loop in following format

```
 for i in {a..z}
```

But this gives , Please suggest the right statement

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using a and z as stand-ins for numbers, in which case the answer using seq should suffice, or if your intention is to generate the alphabet; could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes i want to generate a-z alphabets , not numbers

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a version of seq that works with letters. Do you have perl available? In that case:

```
for i in `perl -e "$,=' '; print a..z"`; do echo $i; done
```

I got the `$,=' '` obscure part here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445452/shell-script-for-loop-syntax

Of course I'm assuming you need to generate dynamic slices of the alphabet, otherwise this is probably not worth the effort and you should stick to:

```
for i in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Thanks for, for i in `perl -e "$,=' '; print a..z"`; do echo $i; done

Answer (score 1):

Ranges only work for bash 3.0+

Your syntax is correct however:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo "$i) Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}"
done
```

Comment: for i in {1..5}; do echp $i; done

Comment: It doesn't works in my case due to older bash version

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: `for i in $(seq 1 5)`